# Does hot-reload pick up changes to assets?

Tags: dart, flutter

Does hot-reload pick up new assets, changed assets, or changes to the pubspec.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**changed assets**: Yes.
**changes to the pubspec.yml**: Maybe. Please check by yourself and do reply with what result you get.

It would be better to restart in such cases. Hot-reload may or may not work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try testing the asset changes again. I tried it myself once, but wasn't certain if I had it right because I'm a flutter noob.

Comment: I have verified through testing that new assets in the pubspec are capture during a hot-reload. And I think changes to existing assets are also captured.